# golang cgo android ndk missing pthread

Tags: go, android-ndk, cgo

I'm trying to make an android executable (not APK) with C bindings in Go. Here are my variables:

```
set GOARCH=arm
set GOOS=linux
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set CC=C:\ndk\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-s -fPIE -pie -rdynamic -Wall -lstdc++ -lbinder -lutils -landroid_runtime -Lbin -linvoke
go build main.go
```

However when I tried to compile it with the settings above, it gives me:

```
# runtime/cgo
c:/ndk/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: cannot find -lpthread
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

After reading a bit about `pthread` on android, it says that `pthread` lib does not exists in android. How to overcome this? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @JimB it works with GOOS=android. Please make your comment as answer and i will mark it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not have a `libpthread`, but the `libc` contains a partial pthread implementation. You can use `GOOS=android` to build the application with the correct `ld` flags.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue while trying to compile golang code on a 386 container targeting armv7;

```
nobody@8b66fe311370:/berrymuch/ports-golang/hello-world$ env | egrep "^QNX|^GO"
QNX_TARGET=/root/bbndk/target_10_3_1_995/qnx6
QNX_HOST=/root/bbndk/host_10_3_1_12/linux/x86
GOARCH=arm
GOARM=7
QNX_CONFIGURATION=/tmp/.rim/bbndk
GOOS=android
nobody@8b66fe311370:/berrymuch/ports-golang/hello-world$ go build
# runtime/cgo
arm-unknown-nto-qnx8.0.0eabi-gcc-4.6.3: error: unrecognized option '-pthread'
nobody@8b66fe311370:/berrymuch/ports-golang/hello-world$
```

Any hint ?